# is df.iloc faster or a numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
id    date        feature1 feature2 feature3
A1    01-01-2019  1        2        3
A2    01-01-2019  3        4        5
A1    01-02-2019  6        7        8
```

(I made up those numbers)

I'd like to form a 3D array, where one axis is id, the other axis is date, the other features. For the example above it'd look like this

```
1 2 3
3 4 5
```

for day 1,

```
6   7   8
nan nan nan
```

for day 2.

So, I'd have a 2x2x3 array (2 ids, 2 days, 3 features).

My real data has 800000 meters, 365 days, and 6 features. I also have a dictionary, `dict_id`, that links id with an index.

My implementation is as follows:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['date'] = data['date'].dt.dayofyear

a,b = data.shape

output = np.full((800000,365,6),np.nan)

for i in range(a):
   output[dict_id[data.iloc[i,0]],data.iloc[i,1],:] = data.iloc[i,2::]
```

The problem with my approach is that it's very slow. What are other ways to do it faster? maybe use a different object? is there a function that allows doing what I want without the for loop?

Comment: As soon as you have a Python loop, you lose all the performances of Pandas or numpy. Is it an option to use a numpy object or function instead of the lookup in `dict_id`?

Comment: Why not just stick with pandas, and do something like `reindex` and use a `MultiIndex` to get the same type of organization as you would with the numpy array

Comment: @SergeBallesta how would that look like? The dictionary just links a meter id, which a string with an index. The index can be anything, meaning: id ```A1``` can have index 0 or 1. @ALollz what would that look like? I used a for loop, because I don't really know how to use the other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to turn `dict_id` to a series, and let go of the `for` loop:

```
s = pd.Series(dict_id)

output[s[data.iloc[:,0]] , data.iloc[:,1], :] =  data.iloc[:, 2::]
```

Comment: of course! I'll try it and see how much faster it is.

Comment: Yes, that's tremendously faster!